# Pandas - Resample on MultiIndex based DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `df` which has a MultiIndex [(latitude, longitude, time)] with the number of rows being 148 x 244 x 90 x 24. For each latitude and longitude, the time is hourly from 2014-01-01 00:00:00 to 2014:03:31 23:00:00.

```
                                                FFDI
latitude    longitude   time    
-39.20000   140.80000   2014-01-01 00:00:00     6.20000
                        2014-01-01 01:00:00     4.10000
                        2014-01-01 02:00:00     2.40000
                        2014-01-01 03:00:00     1.90000
                        2014-01-01 04:00:00     1.70000
                        2014-01-01 05:00:00     1.50000
                        2014-01-01 06:00:00     1.40000
                        2014-01-01 07:00:00     1.30000
                        2014-01-01 08:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 09:00:00     1.00000
                        2014-01-01 10:00:00     1.00000
                        2014-01-01 11:00:00     0.90000
                        2014-01-01 12:00:00     0.90000
                        ... ... ... ...
                        2014-03-31 21:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 22:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 23:00:00     0.50000
            140.83786   2014-01-01 00:00:00     3.20000
                        2014-01-01 01:00:00     2.90000
                        2014-01-01 02:00:00     2.10000
                        2014-01-01 03:00:00     2.90000
                        2014-01-01 04:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 05:00:00     0.90000
                        2014-01-01 06:00:00     1.10000
                        2014-01-01 07:00:00     1.60000
                        2014-01-01 08:00:00     1.40000
                        2014-01-01 09:00:00     1.50000
                        2014-01-01 10:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 11:00:00     0.80000
                        2014-01-01 12:00:00     0.40000
                        ... ... ... ...
                        2014-03-31 21:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 22:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 23:00:00     0.50000
            ... ... ... ...
... ... ...
-33.90000   140.80000   2014-01-01 00:00:00     6.20000
                        2014-01-01 01:00:00     4.10000
                        2014-01-01 02:00:00     2.40000
                        2014-01-01 03:00:00     1.90000
                        2014-01-01 04:00:00     1.70000
                        2014-01-01 05:00:00     1.50000
                        2014-01-01 06:00:00     1.40000
                        2014-01-01 07:00:00     1.30000
                        2014-01-01 08:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 09:00:00     1.00000
                        2014-01-01 10:00:00     1.00000
                        2014-01-01 11:00:00     0.90000
                        2014-01-01 12:00:00     0.90000
                        ... ... ... ...
                        2014-03-31 21:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 22:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 23:00:00     0.50000
            140.83786   2014-01-01 00:00:00     3.20000
                        2014-01-01 01:00:00     2.90000
                        2014-01-01 02:00:00     2.10000
                        2014-01-01 03:00:00     2.90000
                        2014-01-01 04:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 05:00:00     0.90000
                        2014-01-01 06:00:00     1.10000
                        2014-01-01 07:00:00     1.60000
                        2014-01-01 08:00:00     1.40000
                        2014-01-01 09:00:00     1.50000
                        2014-01-01 10:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 11:00:00     0.80000
                        2014-01-01 12:00:00     0.40000
                        ... ... ... ...
                        2014-03-31 21:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 22:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 23:00:00     0.50000

78001920 rows × 1 columns
```

​What I want to achieve is to calculate a daily maximum FFDI value for every 24 hours (13:00:00 of previous day - 12:00:00 of next day) for each latitude and longitude. How to use DataFrame.resample() on a MultiIndex-based DF?

**EDIT: updated requirement**
In other words, daily maximum FFDI value for a date should be calculated using hourly values from 13:00:00 of the previous day to 12:00:00 of the day. The time zone for the `time` column is UTC. This way I can work it out for my time zone. For example, if calculating daily max FFDI for 2014-01-10, I can use hourly FFDI from 2014-01-09 13:00:00 to 2014-01-10 12:00:00.

As per answer by @jezrael I used the following code:

```
df_daily_max = df .groupby(['latitude', 'longitude', pd.Grouper(freq='24H',base=13,loffset='11H',level='time')])['FFDI'].max().reset_index(name='Max FFDI')
```

I was trying to offset time labels by 13 hours so I was expecting the date starting with "2014-01-01" however it started with "2013-12-31 13:00:00".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) in [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with aggregate `max`:

```
df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude', pd.Grouper(freq='D', level='time')])['FFDI'].max().reset_index(name='Max FFDI')
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. This works; however the output is a Series object instead of DataFrame. How to set the name "Max FFDI"?

Comment: @alextc - Use `df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude', pd.Grouper(freq='D', level='time')])['FFDI'].max().reset_index(name='Max FFDI')`

Comment: Great! I am happy to accept your answer. However, I just realised there was an change in my requirement. Please see edited.

Comment: @alextc - I think best is post new question. One possible idea - is possible subtract `13` hours from datetimes first nd then aggregate?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I posted a new question here:`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66871305/pandas-resample-on-multiindex-based-dataframe-and-use-of-offset`

Comment: @alextc - thank you, unfortunatry now I will be offline in few minutes, so I have only suggestion - is possible convert DataFrame to dict (e.g. some rows for sample data)? Or create some sample data for easier working with your DataFrame? Because not easy copy and test it. If no answer can you ping me tomorrow by comment here?

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to work out how to make base and loffset work as the way I expected.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. Are you able to help with this question further to the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66978114/pandas-resample-on-multiindex-based-dataframe-based-on-a-boolean-column