# Pandas - Resample on MultiIndex based DataFrame and use of offset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `df` which has a MultiIndex [(latitude, longitude, time)] with the number of rows being 148 x 244 x 90 x 24. For each latitude and longitude, the time is hourly from `2014-01-01 00:00:00` to `2014:03:31 23:00:00` in the UTC format.

```
                                                FFDI
latitude    longitude   time    
-39.20000   140.80000   2014-01-01 00:00:00     6.20000
                        2014-01-01 01:00:00     4.10000
                        2014-01-01 02:00:00     2.40000
                        2014-01-01 03:00:00     1.90000
                        2014-01-01 04:00:00     1.70000
                        2014-01-01 05:00:00     1.50000
                        2014-01-01 06:00:00     1.40000
                        2014-01-01 07:00:00     1.30000
                        2014-01-01 08:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 09:00:00     1.00000
                        2014-01-01 10:00:00     1.00000
                        2014-01-01 11:00:00     0.90000
                        2014-01-01 12:00:00     0.90000
                        ... ... ... ...
                        2014-03-31 21:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 22:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 23:00:00     0.50000
            140.83786   2014-01-01 00:00:00     3.20000
                        2014-01-01 01:00:00     2.90000
                        2014-01-01 02:00:00     2.10000
                        2014-01-01 03:00:00     2.90000
                        2014-01-01 04:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 05:00:00     0.90000
                        2014-01-01 06:00:00     1.10000
                        2014-01-01 07:00:00     1.60000
                        2014-01-01 08:00:00     1.40000
                        2014-01-01 09:00:00     1.50000
                        2014-01-01 10:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 11:00:00     0.80000
                        2014-01-01 12:00:00     0.40000
                        ... ... ... ...
                        2014-03-31 21:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 22:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 23:00:00     0.50000
            ... ... ... ...
... ... ...
-33.90000   140.80000   2014-01-01 00:00:00     6.20000
                        2014-01-01 01:00:00     4.10000
                        2014-01-01 02:00:00     2.40000
                        2014-01-01 03:00:00     1.90000
                        2014-01-01 04:00:00     1.70000
                        2014-01-01 05:00:00     1.50000
                        2014-01-01 06:00:00     1.40000
                        2014-01-01 07:00:00     1.30000
                        2014-01-01 08:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 09:00:00     1.00000
                        2014-01-01 10:00:00     1.00000
                        2014-01-01 11:00:00     0.90000
                        2014-01-01 12:00:00     0.90000
                        ... ... ... ...
                        2014-03-31 21:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 22:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 23:00:00     0.50000
            140.83786   2014-01-01 00:00:00     3.20000
                        2014-01-01 01:00:00     2.90000
                        2014-01-01 02:00:00     2.10000
                        2014-01-01 03:00:00     2.90000
                        2014-01-01 04:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 05:00:00     0.90000
                        2014-01-01 06:00:00     1.10000
                        2014-01-01 07:00:00     1.60000
                        2014-01-01 08:00:00     1.40000
                        2014-01-01 09:00:00     1.50000
                        2014-01-01 10:00:00     1.20000
                        2014-01-01 11:00:00     0.80000
                        2014-01-01 12:00:00     0.40000
                        ... ... ... ...
                        2014-03-31 21:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 22:00:00     0.30000
                        2014-03-31 23:00:00     0.50000

78001920 rows × 1 columns
```

I need to calculate a daily maximum FFDI value for a date using hourly values from 13:00:00 of the previous day to 12:00:00 of the current day to suit my time zone (+11). For example, if calculating daily max FFDI for 2014-01-10 in the +11 time zone, I can use hourly FFDI from 2014-01-09 13:00:00 to 2014-01-10 12:00:00.

```
df_daily_max = df .groupby(['latitude', 'longitude', pd.Grouper(freq='24H',base=13,loffset='11H',level='time')])['FFDI'].max().reset_index(name='Max FFDI')
```

The calculation starts with 13:00:00 and with a frequency of 24 hours.

The output is:

```
    latitude                    longitude                   time                    Max FFDI
0   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    2013-12-31 13:00:00     6.19999980926513671875
1   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    2014-01-01 13:00:00     1.50000000000000000000
2   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    2014-01-02 13:00:00     1.60000002384185791016
```

... ... ... ...

I would like the output to be:

```
    latitude                    longitude                   time            Max FFDI
0   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    2014-01-01      6.19999980926513671875
1   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    2014-01-02      1.50000000000000000000
2   -39.20000076293945312500    140.80000305175781250000    2014-01-03      1.60000002384185791016
```

... ... ... ...

Comment: So output is correct only need next step - add `13 hours` like `df['time'] += pd.Timedelta(13, unit='H')` ?

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. I was wondering if there was a way to achieve this by running the resample function with configuration settings like `base` or `offset` instead of manipulating the dataframe afterwards. Any thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately not.